# In Java Priority Queue implementation remove at method, why it does a sift up after a sift down?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I have been reading Java collection API, the priority queue part, which is implemented by Josh Bloch and Doug Lea, the two maestros' work.

The Java `PriorityQueue` is implemented with array heap.

The code snippets are here , from `PriorityQueue.java`, Line 600：

```
/**
 * Removes the ith element from queue.
 *
 * Normally this method leaves the elements at up to i-1,
 * inclusive, untouched.  Under these circumstances, it returns
 * null.  Occasionally, in order to maintain the heap invariant,
 * it must swap a later element of the list with one earlier than
 * i.  Under these circumstances, this method returns the element
 * that was previously at the end of the list and is now at some
 * position before i. This fact is used by iterator.remove so as to
 * avoid missing traversing elements.
*/

private E removeAt(int i) {
        // assert i >= 0 && i < size;
        modCount++;
        int s = --size;
       if (s == i) // removed last element
            queue[i] = null;
        else {
            E moved = (E) queue[s];
            queue[s] = null;
            siftDown(i, moved);
            //the code I am asking is below:
            if (queue[i] == moved) {
               siftUp(i, moved);
                if (queue[i] != moved)
                    return moved;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What I am wondered is that, the moved element, which used to be at the bottom of the heap, should be a large one of the sub tree from `i`. The `siftDown` method is reasonable, after a `siftDown`, the smallest of the subtree will be lifted to the position `i`.

The question is, if the `i` does not change, i.e. the moved is still there after `siftDown`, it seems to me that the sub tree has already been heapified, it does not need to be `siftUp` again.

Why Josh lift them up again to the top?

Hope those who has read the code helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the moved item (the item at `queue[size-1]`) might not be in the same subtree as the item that was removed. Consider this heap:

```
      0
  4       1
5   6   2   3
```

Now if you remove the node 5 you have:

```
      0
  4       1
    6   2   3
```

You take the last node in the heap, 3, and put it in the place where 5 was:

```
      0
  4       1
3   6   2
```

You sift 3 down, but it's already a leaf. It's potentially out of place. You have to sift it up to obtain:

```
      0
  3       1
4   6   2
```

Comment: Thanks Jim! A large element in one side of the heap might not be as large as others in the same layer. I think the scenario u desribed might only happened in the leaf level. If the siftDown does not change the position and it has children, the siftUp seems redundent. Is it correct? Hope clarified.

Comment: Add to the previous comment, especially in the array based heap implementation, the only case shall be the leaves.

Comment: @stayclean: This is not restricted to the leaf level. In a larger heap, it could happen many levels above the leaves. You should be able to construct such a case with a heap that's only one level deeper than my example.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If the siftdown does not happened, it only means that the node is the smallest as the previous moved node in its sub tree. This could not guarrantee it is larger than its parent, between the moved node and the parent key value should have enough gap to hold more natural numbers, which has not absolute relation with element on the other side of the heap.